# Flex form inside Pop up window - Tab (order) between forms not working

Tags: apache-flex, popup, tab-ordering

when user clicks on Add button, then a pop up button will be opened with certain form elements (like textinput, date field, text area).. When i used 'TAB' inside this form,it is not working. I found in couple of Questions / forums that we need to create an instance of FocusManager and then  bring/activate focus for the pop up. But still i didn't see the tab working inside the form. In order to tab order working inside a pop up, what steps we need to follow.

I tried using focusmanager and property like tabfocusenabled, tabenabled and also added taborder inside each form element. But no luck.

Iam using Flash Builder 4.5 and using spark components for development.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Thanks in Advance,

Regards

Srinivasan

Comment: Show us some code. Can you tell us what TAB exactly is? Do you mean TabNavigator or custom component? I don't see a reason to put tabnavigator inside a form..

Comment: While bug fixing found the problem is due to the form loaded inside accordion.
Form has been loaded inside horizontal accordion (doug mccune) component. While using tab order was not working.
Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Tab (normal tab order inside form elements) inside a form which loaded inside horizontal accordion. I hope already mentioned in the title as well. If any details needed, let me know.           <s:Form id="srchBtn" textAlign="left" tabFocusEnabled="true" tabEnabled="true">                                                               <s:FormItem label="EAN">
    <s:TextInput id="ean_ti" focusAlpha="0"  tabEnabled="true" tabIndex="1"/>
   </s:FormItem>
   <s:FormItem label="Product number">
    <s:TextInput id="prod_num_ti" focusAlpha="0" />
   </s:FormItem>                             </s:form>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses.

Finally the issue has been solved by one of my colleague. Problem is , the form has been loaded inside Horizontal accordion (flexlib HACCORDION). So inorder to draw focus inside the accordion to child elements, we need to add 'hasFocusableChildren="true"' for the HAccordion (horizontal accordion component). Adding this property solves the tab order problem.

I have also pasted the code below: